# Why are RBAC Service Principals not listed in az ad sp list?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Creating a Service Principal with this command:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n sp-aks-001 --skip-assignment
```

And then listing all service principals with:

```
az ad sp list -o table
```

Does not output the newly created Service Principal. I don't know how to then obtain the object ID of it, since for some reason it is not outputted as part of the create command.

Why is the SP not listed in the last command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, only the first 100 will be returned unless you provide filter arguments or use "--all". So you should use it by either adding the --all flag like below or get your specific SP by filter;

```
az ad sp list --all -o table
```

OR

```
az ad sp list --display-name sp-aks-001 -o table
```

OR use ODATA filter:

```
az ad sp list --filter '<OData filter condition>' -o table
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_sp_list